# How to write a HTTP POST handler in laravel PHP for inbound mailgun emails?

Tags: php, laravel, email, mailgun

http://documentation.mailgun.net/quickstart.html contains some example code for a http handler in Django:

```
# Handler for HTTP POST to http://myhost.com/messages for the route defined above
def on_incoming_message(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
 sender    = request.POST.get('sender')
 recipient = request.POST.get('recipient')
 subject   = request.POST.get('subject', '')

 body_plain = request.POST.get('body-plain', '')
 body_without_quotes = request.POST.get('stripped-text', '')
 # note: other MIME headers are also posted here...

 # attachments:
 for key in request.FILES:
     file = request.FILES[key]
     # do something with the file

# Returned text is ignored but HTTP status code matters:
# Mailgun wants to see 2xx, otherwise it will make another attempt in 5 
minutes
return HttpResponse('OK')
```

What would be the equivalent in PHP?

I have found [this](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php/issues/28) issue leaving us with this info:

> For anyone else who needs the reference, just call $_POST['value'] and
>   make sure to return 200 OK header.

In my web.php I suppose it should be a post-route like so:

```
Route::post('/messages', 'MessageController@store');
```

However when using post I get a MethodNotAllowedHttpException error.

Comment: This tutorial helped me out. 
https://laravel-news.com/laravel-inbound-email

Answer (score 1):

My first guess would be `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware that would cause a problem - if you're running it on the `web` group. Move it to `api` group and see if the exception is gone. Then from the controller method return response with status 200:

```
return new \Illuminate\Http\Response;
```

The defaults will return empty response with status 200.
Don't forget to update the endpoint in mailgun control panel (with prefix for `api` group your route would be `/api/messages`).

Comment: I think you are right. I make another answer with a link that has a more extensive explanation instead.. even though it does not answer my question exactly. I will leave the question open untill someone maybe delivers the exact answer.